# VSTO Outlook: How to know the minimum height of a custom task pane

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, customtaskpane

I have a custom task pane placed at the top of the Outlook. From what Microsoft says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.height?view=vsto-2017) in the remarks:

> The minimum height depends on several factors, and can change in
> future releases of Microsoft Office. If you try to set the Height
> property to a value that is less than the minimum height, the
> application will automatically reassign the Height property to the
> minimum height.

What are these factors?

I would like to know what is the minimum height in advance so I can design my custom task pane with the UI components within it accordingly. Of course, if you put a smaller value Outlook will reassign the minimum height.

Answer (score 0):

I guess scaling factors may play a vital role there. If you design your UI with a flow-layout containers or scaled depending on the DPI value everything will be changed in sized with a task pane correctly. Read more about that in the [Automatic scaling (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/forms/autoscale?view=netdesktop-6.0) section of MSDN.

To find out what is the exact minimum size of the pane set its Width property to 10 and then at runtime you may check results.